# Ubuntu 19.10 KWorker bug. Want to ditch Linux and reinstall Windows10 please help

Tags: cpu

Hi I previously already posted this question but no solutions were offered. One of the responses even went as far as saying that it's not a problem. My CPU1 is running at 80-90% and my laptop (Microsoft Surface Book 2) gets very hot. It is definitely a problem.

I ran the `top` command in my terminal and this showed me that a user, root, is running at 80-90% at any given time and it was related to a kworker. I tried solving this by recompiling the kernel by using jakeday's solution found on github. This also didn't work. I have given up on Linux as I do not want to damage my PC's hardware.

I found upon further research that reinstalling Windows 10 is going to be difficult too now. I installed Ubuntu 19.10 using a USB. Now I want to get rid of that and reinstall Windows 10. How would I manage to do this?

Could you link me to any site/service that could help me with something like that? Or a site that could help me repair the kworker bug? Either would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. This took me a long time, jakeday is very outdated. Anyone reading this should not use his repo. It won't work. Look for the surface-linux subreddit and you will find a github repo to a different kernel named surface-linux.

Follow the directions there and DO NOT create a secure boot. Holding down a combination of keys to get you to the UEFI boot menu, and continue from there. You will see a way to redirect your kernel to point at the appropriate one you require.

DM me if you need help. This is a fairly complicated process. My discord is gsand#8300